# What is Twig Profiler in twig template engine and how do we use it?

Tags: php, twig

**Twig** comes with some extensions, one of these extensions is **Twig_Profiler**, I tried to inject a Profiler object but it does not work:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Profiler(new Twig_Profiler_Profile()));
```

This code won't show me any profiling nor a toolbar (*What Symfony does in its Profiler*).

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

The Twig Profiler is a visual shell for the [symfony profiler](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-twig-profiler) in twig.

By default only requests with a bad response are logged into the profiler.
When you have an exception in your code, the twig profiler toolbar will apear which you can then click to see a detailed overview of the request and the exception

Comment: In spite of exception, twig won't show any toolbar.

Comment: You will also need to enable the profiler within symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html)

Comment: I'm using twig without Symfony (standalone)!! How to do it then?

Comment: I did not find any solution yet, but blackfire.io.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble using the Twig Profiler extension (without Symfony, just plain Twig and PHP) as the documentation is not very clear. I did figure it out though, and just to mention, there is no toolbar that pops up, it is just text output. The toolbar is probably only available if using the entire Symfony framework.

What wasn't clear in the docs is that you have to call `dump()` after you render the template. This is what I did:

```php
// Where you setup Twig:
// ...
$profile = new \Twig\Profiler\Profile();
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\ProfilerExtension($profile));
$GLOBALS['profile'] = $profile;
```

```php
// Where you render the template:
$html = $this->twig->render('my_template.twig', $context);
echo $html;

$profile = $GLOBALS['profile'];
$dumper = new \Twig\Profiler\Dumper\TextDumper();
file_put_contents("twig-profile.prof", $dumper->dump($profile));
```

The `twig-profile.prof` will look something like:

```
main 9.60ms/100%
└ @blog/article.twig 9.60ms/100%
  └ @blog/base.twig 8.84ms/92%
    └ @blog/base.twig::block(head) 6.04ms/63%
    │ └ @blog/article.twig::block(opengraph) 5.93ms/62%
    │ └ @blog/article.twig::block(js)
    │   └ @blog/base.twig::block(js)
    └ @blog/article.twig::block(content) 2.73ms/28%
      └ @blog/comment-form.twig
      │ └ @blog/comment-box-macro.twig::macro(comment_box)
      └ @blog/comment.twig
      └ @blog/comment.twig
      └ @blog/comment.twig
      └ @blog/comment.twig
```